# MySQL upgrade 5.5 to 5.6 created issue

Tags: mysql, linux

I guess before, I was setting up my databases incorrectly by saying the column is not null, and there is no default value. ( I THINK, never paid attention ).

Now after updating to mysql 5.6, a lot of my columns say it is not null and it doesn't have a default value, and when I try to insert something like

values 1 2 3 (but no 4) into column 1 2 3

It fails and gives me an error because column 4 isn't set to null nor does it have a default value. Is there a setting in mysql to bypass this?

I migrated from 5.5 to 5.6

On cent os 6 , php 5.4

Just confused why the database worked before, and not anymore, all I did was export the database and did an import again.

Comment: Check the mysql changelog or instructions; they usually identify what has changed in the newer versions; I'm certain it was some lax restrictions that were tightened in the newer versions.

Comment: One thing you can do is issue the alter statement to update the specific tables/columns to set default values.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I'll end up having to do. They tightened restrictions I believe. What a chore.. just to get full text search from innodb heh..

Comment: Not really; InnoDB on MySQL 5.6 supports [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) now.

Comment: I meant, I upgraded to 5.6 and got all this work to do now, because I wanted to get that :) Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help. Maybe I'll post an answer next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

As of MySQL 5.6.13, the server applies the proper sql_mode checks to generate a warning or error at insert or update time.

A resulting incompatibility for replication if you use statement-based logging (binlog_format=STATEMENT) is that if a slave is upgraded, a nonupgraded master will execute the preceding example without error, whereas the INSERT will fail on the slave and replication will stop.

To deal with this, stop all new statements on the master and wait until the slaves catch up. Then upgrade the slaves followed by the master. Alternatively, if you cannot stop new statements, temporarily change to row-based logging on the master (binlog_format=ROW) and wait until all slaves have processed all binary logs produced up to the point of this change. Then upgrade the slaves followed by the master and change the master back to statement-based logging.

---

After further investigating, turning off mysql strict mode worked in my.cnf file.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + ALT + T (terminal)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
sudo apt-get install phpMySql
```